# How to run a command correct for CMD in remote box using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, remote-access

I need to run a remote command with help of PowerShell from CMD. This is the command I call from CMD:

```
powershell -command "$encpass=convertto-securestring -asplaintext mypass -force;$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList myuser,$encpass; invoke-command -computername "REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME" -scriptblock {<command>} -credential $cred;"
```

in place of `<command>` (including < and > signs) can be any command which can be run in cmd.exe. For example there can be `perl -e "print $^O;"` or `echo "Hello World!"` (NOTE: There cannot be `perl -e 'print $^O;'`, because it is incorrect command for CMD due to the single quotes). So it appears the command `perl -e "print $^O;"` and any other command which contains double quotes doesn't handled as expected. Here I expect it to return OS name of remote box from perl's point of view, but it prints nothing due to obscure handling of double quotes by PowerShell and/or CMD.

So the question is following, how to run command correct for CMD in remote box using PowerShell?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an effect of unescaped quotes (`"`) near REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME?

Comment: @user268396 Yes I am. Generally I've tried with single-quoted REMOTE_COMPUTER_NAME and it doesn't affect to the result of any operation. I can surely tell that the problem is in <command>.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible problems with the command line in the OP. If the command line in the OP is being executed from Powershell itself the $encpass and $cred will get substituted before the (sub-instance) of powershell is invoked. You need to use single quotes or else escape the $ signs, for example:

```
powershell -command "`$encpass=2"
powershell -command '$encpass=2'
```

If, instead of using Powershell, the command line is executed from CMD, then ^ has to be escaped, because it is the CMD escape character.

And quoting " is a good idea as well. In a few tests that I did I had to use unbalanced quotes to get a command to work, for example, from powershell:

powershell -command "`$encpass=`"`"a`"`"`"; write-host `$encpass"

worked, but balanced quotes didn't.

To avoid all this, probably the most robust way to do this is given in powershell command line help: `powershell -?`:

```
# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:
$command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

However there is a new feature in PS 3.0 that is also supposed to help, but I don't think it will be as robust. Described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx, near the middle of the blog.

Comment: This is not what I want. But it helps me to figure out the problem. So I have written `perl -e """print \`$^O;"""` instead of `perl -e "print $^O;"` and it works.